# C# Process.GetProcesses not finding processes unless they are minimized

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to get a list of process that are currently running and it will only list the ones that are minimize? I tried rebooting the computer and still nothing. I tried the code on another computer and it lists both minimize, maximized, and restore processes.

I even tried Process.GetProcessesByName(String) and it will only list the process if it is minimized.

below is the code I used to list the processes.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Find_Proc
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Clear();
            Process[] proc = Process.GetProcesses();
            foreach (Process process in proc)
            {
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(process.MainWindowTitle))
                {
                    listBox1.Items.Add(process.MainWindowTitle);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Both systems were windows 7 or?

Comment: @tweellt Yes both are windows 7

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: You are not listing processes here, but rather the focused window for each process that has one. This code works fine; the problem lies in your expectations. What window titles are you expecting to see and yet do not?

Comment: It is a problem with the try/catch in your code, you didn't post it in your snippet.  It makes your loop exit prematurely.  Thus hiding the real problem.  Never clean up code before you post it.

Comment: @HansPassant The code has not been edited. this is exactly how it is written. I have used this code on 6 of the computers in my office and it works. And it worked on the computer in questioned 2 days ago and now it is not. It will only list the processes that are minimized.

Comment: @Jon If you open Notepad, calculator, paint, and wordpad it will list them all if they are minimized or not. but on the one machine it will only list them if they are minimized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the computer with the problem was windows based. I had the customer ship the compute back and I re-installed windows and I have not seen the issue again.